# MSVC error C2371 "redefinition; different basic types", except I don't see where I'm redefining anything

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types

The full error is

```
1>d:\test\src\search.cpp(130): error C2371: 'Pos' : redefinition; different basic types
1>    d:\test\src\search.cpp(100) : see declaration of 'Pos'
```

- search.cpp, line 130: `Moves(*Pos);` (If I omit this line, the code compiles without error.)
- search.cpp, line 100: `Position *Pos = Mov.ChildPosition;`

The `Moves` constructor is declared: `Moves(Position &Pos);`

`Mov` is a function argument: `void searchMove(Move &Mov)`

Why does MSVC say I'm redefining `Pos`?

**Update 1:** As requested:

- main.cpp, line 32: `Position Pos(TESTF, TESTW, TESTB);`
- main.cpp, line 36: `searchRoot(Pos, 5);`
- moves.cpp, line 467: `Position *NextPosition = new Position(ParentPosition->flags^0x8000, white, black, theirs, ours);`
- moves.cpp, line 474: `Move *Mov = new Move(*NextPosition, piece, square1, square2, capture);`
- search.cpp, line 26: `void searchRoot(Position &Pos, U8 depth)`
- search.cpp, line 32: `Moves Mov(Pos);`

`Position` objects are passed to the constructors of `Move` and `Moves` objects, stored in `ChildPosition` and `ParentPosition` respectively.

**Update 2**: I replaced line 130 with David Norman's suggestion below, and now I'm receiving five "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" errors. This is strange because they all refer to variables declared using `extern` in my search.h file.

**Update 3**: I replaced `extern` with `static` and everything now compiles. I don't understand why I was getting the errors I was. Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Could you post more code? It is hard to determine what the problem is from this code? There may be more to the issue than what you posted.

Comment: Not a problem, but what code should I post?

Comment: Places where you declare `Pos`.

Comment: You have a `Moves` macro defined somewhere...?

Comment: Drop your crystal balls and close the question.

Comment: @SigTerm: Thanks for the suggestion, but I got the same errors.

Comment: For your "update 2", this is a different question, so you should start a new topic.  Anyway, `extern` is a promise to the compiler that you'll provide that variable in another file.  If you break that promise, the linker will find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to create a Moves object on line 130, then try giving it a name:

```
Moves dummyMoves(*Pos);
```

Otherwise you are probably declaring a variable named Pos of type Moves *

Comment: The `Moves` class generates a list of `Move` objects in its constructor. It isn't used for any other purpose, so I didn't see a reason to give instances names.

Comment: "Otherwise you are probably declaring a variable named Pos of type Moves *"

What leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: I replaced line 130 with your suggestion and am now receiving a whole new set of "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" errors. This is getting me closer to the solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Svad: It's because extra parentheses and whitespace are ignored in variable declarations.  Does `Moves* Pos;` look more like a variable declaration?  The only difference is parentheses.